# Export list of dictionaries to Excel file

Tags: python, json, csv, web-scraping

I'm trying to export some JSONs to an excel file, such that the keys are the headers. I've created a list of dictionaries, and my code is, as of now, as follows:

```
import requests
import json
import csv
from csv import DictWriter

list_json = ['a705932387657456c4a535355794d45786c5a326c7a6247463064584a684c314a6c5a326c7a644739436157396e636d466d61574e7657456c4a53563971633239754c6e523464413d3d&fich=RegistoBiograficoXIII_json.txt&Inline=true', 'a705932387657456c4a4a5449775447566e61584e7359585231636d4576556d566e61584e3062304a706232647959575a705932395953556c66616e4e76626935306548513d&fich=RegistoBiograficoXII_json.txt&Inline=true', 'a705932387657456b6c4d6a424d5a5764706332786864485679595339535a57647063335276516d6c765a334a685a6d6c6a6231684a5832707a6232347564486830&fich=RegistoBiograficoXI_json.txt&Inline=true', 'a7059323876574355794d45786c5a326c7a6247463064584a684c314a6c5a326c7a644739436157396e636d466d61574e7657463971633239754c6e523464413d3d&fich=RegistoBiograficoX_json.txt&Inline=true', 'a7059323876566b6c4a535355794d45786c5a326c7a6247463064584a684c314a6c5a326c7a644739436157396e636d466d61574e76566b6c4a53563971633239754c6e523464413d3d&fich=RegistoBiograficoVIII_json.txt&Inline=true', 'a7059323876566b6c4a535355794d45786c5a326c7a6247463064584a684c314a6c5a326c7a644739436157396e636d466d61574e76566b6c4a53563971633239754c6e523464413d3d&fich=RegistoBiograficoVIII_json.txt&Inline=true', 'a7059323876566b6c4a4a5449775447566e61584e7359585231636d4576556d566e61584e3062304a706232647959575a705932395753556c66616e4e76626935306548513d&fich=RegistoBiograficoVII_json.txt&Inline=true', 'a7059323876566b6b6c4d6a424d5a5764706332786864485679595339535a57647063335276516d6c765a334a685a6d6c6a62315a4a5832707a6232347564486830&fich=RegistoBiograficoVI_json.txt&Inline=true', 'a7059323876566955794d45786c5a326c7a6247463064584a684c314a6c5a326c7a644739436157396e636d466d61574e76566c3971633239754c6e523464413d3d&fich=RegistoBiograficoV_json.txt&Inline=true', 'a70593238765356596c4d6a424d5a5764706332786864485679595339535a57647063335276516d6c765a334a685a6d6c6a62306c575832707a6232347564486830&fich=RegistoBiograficoIV_json.txt&Inline=true', 'a705932387653556c4a4a5449775447566e61584e7359585231636d4576556d566e61584e3062304a706232647959575a705932394a53556c66616e4e76626935306548513d&fich=RegistoBiograficoIII_json.txt&Inline=true', 'a705932387653556b6c4d6a424d5a5764706332786864485679595339535a57647063335276516d6c765a334a685a6d6c6a62306c4a5832707a6232347564486830&fich=RegistoBiograficoII_json.txt&Inline=true', 'a7059323876513239756333527064485670626e526c4c314a6c5a326c7a644739436157396e636d466d61574e765132397563313971633239754c6e523464413d3d&fich=RegistoBiograficoCons_json.txt&Inline=true']

result = []

for i in list_json:
    url = 'http://app.parlamento.pt/webutils/docs/doc.txt?path=6148523063446f764c324679626d56304c3239775a57356b595852684c3052685a47397a51574a6c636e5276637939535a576470633352764a544977516d6c765a334c446f575{}'.format(i)
    r = requests.get(url)
    cont = r.json()
    result.append(cont)


with open('bio.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = DictWriter(outfile, ('?xml', 'RegistoBiografico'))
    writer.writerows(result)
```

I expected the export to work, and to get a csv file as intended. The output of my exportation attempt is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\fnac\Desktop\Universidade do Minho\Software\lib\csv.py", line 158, in writerows
    return self.writer.writerows(map(self._dict_to_list, rowdicts))
  File "C:\Users\fnac\Desktop\Universidade do Minho\Software\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25fe' in position 103992: character maps to <undefined>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failure is due to opening the output file without specifying the encoding.  On your system it defaulted to `cp1252` and the file content used Unicode codepoints that don't map into that encoding.  Use `utf8` or `utf-8-sig` instead.  `utf-8-sig` is ideal if Excel is used to view the CSV.  Also use `newline=''` per [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) documentation.

```
with open('bio.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as outfile:
```

Comment: That helped a lot! Thank you